# How can I try and make people want to do things with me and talk to me?

Tags: conversations, united-kingdom, socializing, autism-spectrum

If you don't know, this is sort of an extension to a [question that I asked a while ago on this site.](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/1399/why-dont-people-initiate-conversations-with-me)

I really need some help because people don't start conversations with me and no one wants to do anything with me. I keep trying to initiate conversations with people but it ends within 2 seconds because they don't talk back to me. I don't understand why but I feel like no one wants me/cares about me a lot.

I get incredibly confused throughout the day because I find it quite hard to understand what's going on around me or why people are saying things to me, and it makes me so upset and worried/scared. I really don't know what to do. I ask myself questions like:

- Why are they saying that to me?
- Why did he/she do that to me?
- Why doesn't he/she care about me?
- Why can't I be the one who is talked to?
- Why is he/she ignoring me?
- Why can't I be more significant?

And I just can't answer the questions. I'm not deluded and I don't think anyone should talk to me I just can't think of the answer.

I have tried to solve the problems myself by trying to make people do things with me or talk to me. I have tried so many things but people always so no to me. I feel like a lot of people only talk to me to pass the time.

What can I do? I really want someone to want me. Is it the way I look or act? I just want to know why I can't be significant and important to anyone.

Comment: Can you narrow it down a bit, e. g. give an example?

Comment: I don't really know what kind of example I can give, it's a very general thing that just happens all day. People don't respond to me when I talk to them, that type of thing @AnneDaunted

Comment: The question in its current form is too broad to be answered.

Comment: "People don't respond to me when I talk to them" - can you give examples of what you say that people don't respond to? It would also help to have context of who you're talking to - a stranger in a coffee shop? A coworker at work?